# How to dynamically copy tables from information schema inside a trigger function

Tags: postgresql

I have an insert trigger function in which NEW.schema_name references a schema. I want to dynamically copy the tables found inside that schema ('foobaz','barbaz') as 'foo' and 'bar'. I then can perform queries without dynamic sql.

How can I create a function or simply copy/paste the same block of code to achive that.

EDIT :

I cannot get that dynamic query to work. 
The part inside the WITH statement is working.
Not the bottom 'execute' part. I do not know if it is a syntax problem, or bad cast or whatever constraint there is in pgsql that makes it not working.

```
WITH info_schema_subset_table as (SELECT table_schema, table_name, 
     array_to_string((regexp_split_to_array(table_name,'_'))[4:array_length(regexp_split_to_array(table_name,'_'),1)-1] as new_table
     FROM information_schema.tables
     where table_schema = "schema_searched"
     ORDER BY new_table ASC)

  EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE $2 as (SELECT * FROM $1)'
  USING info_schema_subset_table.table_schema || '.' ||info_schema_subset_table.table_name,info_schema_subset_table.new_table;
```

EDIT 2

... Broken code removed...

In the code below, in which I'm unsure if the syntax is right, I get the following from the trigger

> Provider errors:
>         PostGIS error while adding features: ERREUR:  l'opérateur n'existe pas : record ~~ unknown
>       LINE 1: SELECT old_table LIKE '%ens%'
>                                ^
>       HINT:  Aucun opérateur ne correspond au nom donné et aux types d'arguments.
>       Vous devez ajouter des conversions explicites de type.
>       QUERY:  SELECT old_table LIKE '%ens%'
>       CONTEXT:  fonction PL/pgsql validation_sio.afi_validation_sio(), ligne 18 à CASE

EDIT 3 :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo.foo()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$

DECLARE 
old_table record;
new_table record;
dynamic_query text;

BEGIN

IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
THEN

FOR old_table IN SELECT table_schema|| '.' ||table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
where table_schema = NEW.nom_schema
LOOP

CASE 
 WHEN
  old_table LIKE '%ens%' THEN
  new_table := concat('SIT_',array_to_string((regexp_split_to_array(info_schema.old_table,'_'))[4:array_length(regexp_split_to_array(info_schema.old_table,'_'),1)-1],'_'));
 ELSE 
  new_table := concat('SID_',array_to_string((regexp_split_to_array(info_schema.old_table,'_'))[4:array_length(regexp_split_to_array(info_schema.old_table,'_'),1)-1],'_'));
END CASE;

dynamic_query := format('SELECT * FROM' || old_table ||);
EXECUTE dynamic_query
INTO new_table;

END LOOP;

RETURN NEW;

END IF;
END; 
$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;


CREATE TRIGGER foo
AFTER INSERT ON validation.validationfoo
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo.foo();
```

Comment: Don't use `is` as an alias, it's a postgres keyword.

Comment: You're using `format` incorrectly. Either do `dynamic_query := 'SELECT * FROM' || old_table` or do `dynamic_query := format('SELECT * FROM %s', old_table)`.

Comment: I didn't understand [format] at all. Thanks. It is similar to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reformatted your trigger function a bit and changed a few things, see if this works.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo.foo()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    old_table record;
    new_table record;
    dynamic_query text;
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        FOR old_table IN
            SELECT table_schema || '.' || table_name AS old_table_name
            FROM information_schema.tables
            WHERE table_schema = NEW.nom_schema
        LOOP
            new_table := concat(CASE WHEN old_table.old_table_name LIKE '%ens%' THEN 'SIT_' ELSE 'SID_' END,array_to_string((regexp_split_to_array(info_schema.old_table,'_'))[4:array_length(regexp_split_to_array(info_schema.old_table,'_'),1)-1],'_'));
            dynamic_query := 'CREATE TABLE ' || new_table || ' AS SELECT * FROM ' || old_table.old_table_name;
            EXECUTE dynamic_query;
        END LOOP;

        RETURN NEW;
    END IF;
END; 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

So the main things:

- `old_table` is a record, so your comparison of it to a string with `LIKE` was failing. You need to use the field name. So I gave your field a name, and used that field name in the `LIKE` comparison.
- Changed the `new_table` assignment to put the `CASE` statement only on the one item that changes, to make the difference more obvious and the code more concise. Mind you, I don't know if the rest of that line is actually valid, I just left it as is.
- Changed the creation `dynamic_query`. As I said in the comment, the `format` function was being used incorrectly, so I just went with standard string concatenation instead.
- Changed `dynamic_query`'s SQL to what I think you actually want it to do. You want it to copy the content of the table to a new table, right? So that will do it.

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injection. If I create a table with the right name, I can break your function or abuse it.

Comment: Sure, although I'm not too bothered because for one thing, this is simply getting making some changes to the OP's code to do what he wants, it's not a comprehensive example of the perfect trigger; and secondly the data used to create the dynamic sql statement is taken entirely from existing data in tables, and we don't know whether users have any access to write to those tables etc.

Comment: Ok to the first part, but we *do* know what users have write access to these tables: everybody who can create a table. I'm not saying that your answer is bad, I just think it can be improved. Enough people slavishly copy code examples like yours and use them as gold standard. Not your fault, but I think we should raise awareness for SQL injection wherever we can.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have `EXECUTE` inside an SQL statement, it is a PL/pgSQL statement.

Loop through the tables and issue one `EXECUTE` for each.

Mind that you cannot have a schema or table name as a parameter with `USING`, because these names need to be known at parse time.

Use the `format` function to construct your dynamic statement so you can avoid SQL injection by users who maliciously create tables with weird names.

Comment: Can you look at my edit and tell me if it seems right?

Comment: The edited code is full of syntax errors, statements without ending semicolon, loops without `END LOOP` and similar, so it's hard to say. But you are moving in the right direction. Also, you are still vulnerable to SQL injection by weird table names. My advice with the `DO` statement was misguided - I didn't realize you were in PL/pgSQL code (you didn't post the whole function). So you don't need a `DO` statement.

Comment: Ok, that is what I was thinking.  Does format prevent injection? From what I understand, a table name could correspond to a query being injected. Does Format prevent that by quoting all the names? I am more or less new to sql...

Comment: IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
THEN
I get an error right after the FOR, is my syntax right?
FOR info_schema IN SELECT table_schema|| '.' ||table_name as old_table

Comment: No, your syntax is broken beyond repair. Begin by removing the `DO` statement. Every statement has to end with `;`, every `IF` needs an `END IF;`, every `LOOP` needs and `END LOOP;`. Begin along these lines and proceed.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It helped me a lot understanding some subtlety I'm unfamiliar with.